# How to record all updates and insertions for a database for a specific time period

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a remote db for which I like to record all changes ( updates and inserts ) for the next couple of hours. If necessary I like to revert all changes as well. Note, that all of the changes might be coming in from several users/applications.

The db is fairly small ( couple of GBs ) and the number of updates should be small too ( < 1000 ).

How would I do that with SQL Server 2008 R2?

Let me know if you need more information.

Thanks,
Christian

Comment: I would create a backup at a specific point in time then run your changes. If you need to restore then you can use the previous backup. I don't know of a method that allows commit/rollback on such a wide scope

Comment: Too bad, I thought that would be a nice feature. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So many options, depending on your exact needs and what you have available:

- Take a full backup when the database is in the "before" state. Use a data comparison tool to determine what changed.
- Create a [database snapshot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) (Enterprise Edition engine only). This will let you see the before state at all times, and you can manually consolidate/rollback/whatever the changes that get made, or revert to the snapshot which will essentially do the same thing as a restore. Use a data comparison tool to determine what changed.
- Use [Change Data Capture (CDC)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx) (Enterprise Edition engine only). This will capture all the changes made to the tables on which it's enabled. This is a really granular approach. Combine with either a backup or snapshot to roll back.
- Set up triggers on all the tables that can be affected, and direct the data to change tracking tables you create yourself. Combine with either a backup or snapshot to roll back.